# Multiple requests with dredd yml

Tags: node.js, rest, yaml, dredd

Using node dredd against my API.
I opted for using yml file as this is a std that is familiar with my team.

Here is an example snippet we have functioning correctly:

```
  /api/station/{id}:
    get:
      produces:
        - application/json; charset=utf-8
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
        description: DynamoDB ID of the station to edit
        x-example: 'daf04a00-c3bf-11e7-a913-b76623d265c4'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Returns a single station
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/station'
```

I think I can guess how to define alternate response object, i assume just add to the object eg:

```
  responses:
    200:
      description: Returns a single station
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/station'
    422:
      description: Failed validation
```

In the dredd docs: https://dredd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-guides.html#multiple-requests-and-responses-within-one-api-blueprint-action

There is an example how to send multiple requests to the same end point.. but this is for the API Blueprint format and not yaml.

Does anyone know how to pass multiple requests to the same endpoint using the yaml format? I cannot see any docs on how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right below the section in docs you linked there's [Testing non-2xx Responses with Swagger](https://dredd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-guides.html#testing-non-2xx-responses-with-swagger):

> The [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) format allows to specify multiple responses for a single operation.
>   By default Dredd tests only responses with `2xx` status codes. Responses with other
>   codes are marked as *skipped* and can be activated in hooks - see Testing non-2xx Responses with Swagger.
>
> [Default responses](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#user-content-responsesDefault) are ignored by Dredd. Also, as of now,
>   only `application/json` media type is supported in [`produces`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#user-content-swaggerProduces) and [`consumes`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#user-content-swaggerConsumes).
>   Other media types are skipped.

Comment: Ah, as the title above was obvious to its purpose for the blueprint.. the following title was missed. I added a pull request to the docs at this point, hopefully might help anyone else.